# update android contact ringtone

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm tryin gto change a contact ringtone but I got this error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: custom_ringtone (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE data SET data11=?,custom_ringtone=?,data10=?,data1=?,data2=? WHERE _id =?

and this is my code :

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(ContactID), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, myringtone.getAbsolutePath());
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, myringtone.getAbsolutePath()); //that was my alternative solution because I didn't know which property to change 
    ops.add(builder.build());

    ContentProviderResult[] res;
    try
    {
        res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                        }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Am I missing something ??

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution using  ContentValues instead of ContentProviderOperations:

```
Cursor c;
    c = getContentResolver().query(
        CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
        new String[]{ContactID}, null);

    try 
    {
         c.moveToFirst();
         Uri localUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, ContactID);
         ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
         localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, ringtonefileabsolutepath);
         getContentResolver().update(localUri, localContentValues, null, null); 

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
         c.close();
    }
```